# Populating dropdown with sql results

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following code to display a dropdown based on the sql query but nothing is displaying when i run the code.

```
<?php
require ("common.php");

$sql = "SELECT FullName FROM Users";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$option = "";
while($rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$name = $rows["FullName"];
$option.="<option>".$name."</option>";
}
?>

<div class="aClass">
<p class="select">Name</p>
<select name="aName" id="aName">
<option value="0">Select UserName</option>
<?php echo $option?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: In your PHP code you are adding options to the `$option` variable but then you refer to it as `$options` in your HTML.  Variable is not the same ('s' at the end) and hence no output.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP changed Question to incorporate Answer. The error was a typo 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$option` you added an s

```
<?php echo $option;?>
```

Replace while with

```
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $rows) {

...
}
```

`while($rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` will return the entire set of results which will not evaluate to true,leaving `$name` undefined,you want to iterate over the results.